# setInterval only executing once inside of the jQuery each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, setinterval

I have 3 span elements with the id of "cursor", but the below function executes only for the first element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cursor").each(function(i, current) {
    console.log("ran");
    var $current = $(current);
    setInterval(function() {
      cursorAnimation($current)
    }, 600);
  });
});

function cursorAnimation($obj) {
  $obj.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 'fast', 'swing').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 'fast', 'swing');
}
```

Comment: First thing is that you shouldn't have more than 1 element on the page with the same id...

Comment: As @KeithRousseau says, IDs should only refer to ONE element. If you want to define a group of elements, use a `class` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID selector will return only 0 or 1 DOM elements according to the [JQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). You should not assign an ID to more than one element. Change the ID to a class and use the class selector `$(".class")`

Comment: wow, that was a silly mistake. Thank you!